# Declaration or statement expected. ts(1128)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I wanted to export a function and use it in the ReactJS component in my Javascript code, but when I tried to export the latter, the system showed me an error at the level of the export instruction, saying:

> Declaration or statement expected. ts(1128)

would you please help me fix this error?

```js
function close_sidebar() {
  $("div#sidebar").css("display", "none");
  $("div#rest").css("margin-left", "4px");
  $("div#rest").css("width", "100%");
  $("li#opensidebar").css("display", "block");
}

export close_sidebar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the export statement to the same line as the function definition:

```
export function close_sidebar() {
  $("div#sidebar").css("display", "none");
  $("div#rest").css("margin-left", "4px");
  $("div#rest").css("width", "100%");
  $("li#opensidebar").css("display", "block");
}
```